# \KernelObjects\LowMemoryCondition & \KernelObjects\MaximumCommitCondition

Tags: memory-management, 32bit-64bit, low-memory

I have an application running as a service on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, 64bit version with 32GB of ram.

The application itself doesn't seem to use over 3.4GB of ram (suspicious limit?)

In resource monitor the application is showing the

```
\KernelObjects\LowMemoryCondition
\KernelObjects\MaximumCommitCondition
```

events, even though there is 27192MB of available memory on the server.

Am I just stuck with an application that was written for a 32bit OS?

Comment: "Am I just stuck with an application that was written for a 32bit OS?" - it seems so. What is this application (what language/platform, etc. could you share it's name?)

Comment: It is some external software. No sorry I cannot share the name of the software. .net I believe from some of the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

This objects are created by the [CreateMemoryResourceNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-creatememoryresourcenotification) API. Their presence does not indicate that the high or lower memory condition exists.